# JSON Parsing not looping into CSV right

Tags: python, json, csv

Hi so I am trying to parse out an output of an api but it only prints out 1 row and I have multiple rows. Can anyone help me why my loop is not working and provide a quick work around?

```
import urllib2
import csv
import json
import io
import codecs
import time

with open('/home/local/testpy2.csv',
          'rb') as csvinput:
    #output='testing1.csv'
    #writer=csv.writer(open(output,'w'))
    #headers =[address1]
    #wrtier.writerow(headers)
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter=',')
    firstline = True
    for row in reader:
        if firstline:
            firstline = False
            continue

        address1 = row[0]
        #print row[0]
        locality = row[1]
        admin_area = row[2]
        query = ' '.join(str(x) for x in (address1, locality, admin_area))
        normalized = query.replace(" ", "+")
        BaseURL = 'http://localhost:8081/verify?country=MEX&freeform='
        URL = BaseURL + normalized
        #print URL
        data = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
        response = data.getcode()
    time.sleep(2)
    print response

        if response == 200:
            file= json.load(data)
        #print file

        output_f=open('output2.csv','wb')
        writer=csv.writer(output_f)
        header=['address1','address2','address3','address4','address5','verification_status','max_address_precision','adminstrative_area','thoroughfare']
        writer.writerow(header)     
            #count = 0
    for f in file:
        row=[]
        try:
                row.append(str(f['address1'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['address2'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['address3'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['address4'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['address5'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['analysis']['verification_status'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['analysis']['address_precision'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['analysis']['max_address_precision'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['components']['administrative_area'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        try:
                row.append(str(f['components']['thoroughfare'].encode('utf-8')))
        except:
                row.append('')
        print row
        writer.writerow(row)

    else:
            print 'error'
```

This script is successful in parsing but fails to put all the row into my csv. It only does the first one.

Comment: Your indentation is bad so the example does not run. Could you also try to provide a *minimal* example that does not do what you expect? ie. break your code into small pieces, test each of them, and tell use which one does not behave as expected.

Comment: Apart from the broken indentation, your code does this: `for line in input_file: ( open output_file; write header )`. It doesn't seem to do anything with the data. I rewrote it here - https://repl.it/CfEe - unable to test it obv, which is more how I would expect it to look.